# Inflate Exception in Android after changing themes?

Tags: android, xml, styles, themes, android-manifest

I've recently changed my themes for all my activities in AndroidManifest.xml so that actionbar can show up and all of a sudden I'm getting the following error:

```
12-13 21:06:06.823    1288-1288/tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication/tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
                at tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
                at tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
                at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:117)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
                at tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/eater_accnt"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:parentActivityName="tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication.HomeActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication.HomeActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="tutorial.com.example.jerryhou.myapplication.DisplaySavesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_saves"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

v21\Styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: MainActivity is extending which class?

Comment: MainActivity extends Activity

Answer (score 0):

You have an `OutOfMemoryError` error when loading a Bitmap.

Your new theme probably cause the loading of a huge image (or too many small ones).

Comment: Any suggestions on other less memory intensive themes. I just need a theme that has an actionbar

Comment: maybe you are using very big icon only in xxhdpi resources folder, so it must be decoded and rescaled? Or other drawables/png's

Comment: I'm using all 48x48 .png icons that are < 1000 bytes.  Except for a 2.49 MG .jpg. But all these icons have shown up and worked fine in the past, except for the .jpg that didn't shown up. But the app was still running in the emulator without crashing